# Alternative lyrics to Toad the Wet Sproket's "Something's Always Wrong"

Tags: lyrics, alternative-rock

The song is [Toad the Wet Sprocket's *Something's Always Wrong*](https://youtu.be/8m8Nlz6FLSA).

The videos I can find in internet are all about the normal song lyrics (which is fine, you know, the song, at least to me, is a good one).

But the thing is, looking for the lyrics on the internet, at the end of the song appeared some [additional lyrics](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/toadthewetsprocket/somethingsalwayswrong.html) with a number between brackets or "[]."  Can somebody tell me why is that?  Not all lyrics sites include the alternative lyrics, but still.

Did you know where I can hear that part of the song? Is it like the "Off voices" in that video?  Or is it an alternative lyric like in other songs I know?

I appreciate any effort in trying to solve this doubt, especially if someone has a video where these special lyrics will be clearly evident.

Answer (score 2):

Those are the lyrics being sung by the backing vocals during the chorus.